# Error when creating 2 vue instances for 2 pages (in project laravel + vuejs)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, instance, laravel-blade

I want to create 2 vue instances for 2 pages (one for client site and another for admin). But I got error:

[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

(found in )

My code is below:
**Concept in folder /resources/js/**

```
.
├── admin
│   ├── admin.js
│   ├── components
│   └── views
│       └── Admin.vue
├── bootstrap.js
├── site
│   ├── components
│   │   └── Product.vue
│   ├── routes.js
│   ├── site.js
│   └── views
│       └── Site.vue
└── views
    └── App.vue
```

**admin.js**

```
require('./../bootstrap');

import Admin from './views/Admin.vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
// import router from './routes.js';

window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.use(VueRouter);



const adminapp = new Vue({
    el: '#adminapp',
    components: { Admin }
});
```

**site.js**

```
require('./../bootstrap');

import App from './views/Site.vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import router from './routes.js';

window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.use(VueRouter);


const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: { App },
    router
});
```

**admin.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Admin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="adminapp">
        <adminapp></adminapp>
    </div>

    <script src="{{ asset('/js/admin.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <app id="app"></app>

    <script src="{{ asset('/js/site.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know this problem?

Comment: what is setup for `webpack.mix.js`

Comment: can you show where the component you created is?

Comment: This is setup for `webpack.mix.js`

Comment: `mix.js('resources/js/site/site.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/admin/admin.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .js('node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js', 'public/js').sourceMaps();`